# Flutter Deamon not running when connecting with a physical device

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-doctor

When I plug my physical device with a USB the app does not run.I am using visual studio code and working on a mac.

When I try to run the app it says The Flutter Deamon is not working.Even though I have connected with the device it says

No devices found yet. Checking for wireless devices...
Unable to run "adb", check your Android SDK installation and ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable: /usr/local/Caskroom/android-platform-tools/34.0.4/platform-tools/adb
Exited (1)

Here is my flutter doctor output

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.5, on macOS 13.4.1 22F82 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.80.0)
Error 1 retrieving device properties for RMX3195:
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
ADB server didn't ACK
Full server startup log: /var/folders/33/xy68224j33l6d4tygq1bvh200000gn/T//adb.501.log
Server had pid: 47534
--- adb starting (pid 47534) ---
07-12 19:49:11.977 47534 364459 I adb     : main.cpp:63 Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
07-12 19:49:11.977 47534 364459 I adb     : main.cpp:63 Version 34.0.4-10411341
07-12 19:49:11.977 47534 364459 I adb     : main.cpp:63 Installed as /usr/local/Caskroom/android-platform-tools/34.0.4/platform-tools/adb
07-12 19:49:11.977 47534 364459 I adb     : main.cpp:63 Running on Darwin 22.5.0 (x86_64)
07-12 19:49:11.977 47534 364459 I adb     : main.cpp:63 
07-12 19:49:11.985 47534 364462 I adb     : usb_osx.cpp:325 reported max packet size for SSU84HHQPVF6OBIF is 512
07-12 19:49:12.081 47534 364459 I adb     : auth.cpp:416 adb_auth_init...
07-12 19:49:12.082 47534 364459 I adb     : auth.cpp:152 loaded new key from '/Users/nyuad/.android/adbkey' with fingerprint
839D1793C3734032E863AEFE1FEDF262A3F10481D230C363B1E1C26971F29F79
07-12 19:49:12.082 47534 364465 I adb     : transport.cpp:335 SSU84HHQPVF6OBIF: read thread spawning
07-12 19:49:12.082 47534 364466 I adb     : transport.cpp:307 SSU84HHQPVF6OBIF: write thread spawning
07-12 19:49:12.082 47534 364467 I adb     : transport.cpp:335 emulator-5554: read thread spawning
07-12 19:49:12.082 47534 364468 I adb     : transport.cpp:307 emulator-5554: write thread spawning
07-12 19:49:12.085 47534 364459 I adb     : transport.cpp:1727 fetching keys for transport SSU84HHQPVF6OBIF
07-12 19:49:12.085 47534 364459 I adb     : auth.cpp:468 Calling send_auth_response
07-12 19:49:12.090 47534 364459 I adb     : adb.cpp:175 emulator-5554: already offline
07-12 19:49:12.094 47534 364459 I adb     : adb.cpp:179 SSU84HHQPVF6OBIF: offline

* failed to start daemon
adb: cannot connect to daemon


Error 1 retrieving device properties for sdk gphone64 x86 64:
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
ADB server didn't ACK
Full server startup log: /var/folders/33/xy68224j33l6d4tygq1bvh200000gn/T//adb.501.log
Server had pid: 47536
--- adb starting (pid 47536) ---
07-12 19:49:13.283 47536 364475 I adb     : main.cpp:63 Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
07-12 19:49:13.283 47536 364475 I adb     : main.cpp:63 Version 34.0.4-10411341
07-12 19:49:13.283 47536 364475 I adb     : main.cpp:63 Installed as /usr/local/Caskroom/android-platform-tools/34.0.4/platform-tools/adb
07-12 19:49:13.283 47536 364475 I adb     : main.cpp:63 Running on Darwin 22.5.0 (x86_64)
07-12 19:49:13.283 47536 364475 I adb     : main.cpp:63 
07-12 19:49:13.303 47536 364479 I adb     : usb_osx.cpp:325 reported max packet size for SSU84HHQPVF6OBIF is 512
07-12 19:49:13.389 47536 364475 I adb     : auth.cpp:416 adb_auth_init...
07-12 19:49:13.389 47536 364475 I adb     : auth.cpp:152 loaded new key from '/Users/nyuad/.android/adbkey' with fingerprint
839D1793C3734032E863AEFE1FEDF262A3F10481D230C363B1E1C26971F29F79
07-12 19:49:13.390 47536 364483 I adb     : transport.cpp:335 SSU84HHQPVF6OBIF: read thread spawning
07-12 19:49:13.390 47536 364484 I adb     : transport.cpp:307 SSU84HHQPVF6OBIF: write thread spawning
07-12 19:49:13.390 47536 364485 I adb     : transport.cpp:335 emulator-5554: read thread spawning
07-12 19:49:13.390 47536 364486 I adb     : transport.cpp:307 emulator-5554: write thread spawning
07-12 19:49:13.391 47536 364475 I adb     : transport.cpp:1727 fetching keys for transport SSU84HHQPVF6OBIF
07-12 19:49:13.391 47536 364475 I adb     : auth.cpp:468 Calling send_auth_response
07-12 19:49:13.397 47536 364475 I adb     : adb.cpp:175 emulator-5554: already offline
07-12 19:49:13.399 47536 364475 I adb     : adb.cpp:179 SSU84HHQPVF6OBIF: offline

* failed to start daemon
adb: cannot connect to daemon


[✓] Connected device (5 available)
[✓] Network resources

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
nyuad@13---Mac-Mini notification % 
nyuad@13---Mac-Mini notification %
```

I have added the path of the SDK in the mac OS's path but still it is showing the same error

Comment: Hi @Airin Haque, just for identifying the issue, have you tried running without visual studio code, from your terminal?  Because sometimes, IDE/Text Editors don't pick environment variables for some reason(s). Thanks.

Comment: Hey, I just figured it out. The issue is with the latest version of platform tools , sdk, adb that comes with android studio. They published it this month so I guess thats the issue. When I replaced the platform tools from 2022 it started working and there is no issue running the app from any IDE

Comment: Hi @Airin Haque, I am glad you figured it out. Can you please either close your issue or post your own answer and mark your answer as answered, whatever seems appropriate to you. Thanks :)